# InterfaceOrientation issues when popping a ViewController off the stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the beginnings of my app working pretty well but I have one small issue that I can't figure out how to fix.

It's a view based app and I have a NavigationController in my appDelegate file which is pushing various ViewControllers as required.  Going in the "forwards direction" everything works well, seems perfect actually, but the problem I have is when VC's are popped off the stack. This is the code I'm using to show the VC and then just using the back button to go back.

```
UINavigationController *iaxNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
LogInViewController *logInVC = [[LogInViewController alloc] init];
[iaxNC pushViewController:logInVC animated:NO];
[logInVC release];
[_window addSubview:iaxNC.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

That loads my login view and then the code checks to see if there are any users before it loads the SetUp screen (if there are none) as follows:

```
setUpVC = [[SetUpViewController alloc] init];
setUpVC.firstUse = self.firstUse;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:setUpVC animated:YES];
[setUpVC release];
```

The problem happens when I hit the back button from the SetUp view to go back to the LogIn view.

I have a portrait and a landscape view for most of the VC's and these VC's are subclasses of Michael Tyson's [TPMultiLayoutViewController](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPMultiLayoutViewController).  The portrait view is hooked up as *portraitView and also as *view, the landscape view is hooked up as *landscapeView.

The problem is this:

If I push a VC into view and change the orientation of the device before I hit the back button then when I do hit "Back" the previous VC is displayed in its original format (i.e. NOT rotated to the current orientation) it also appears that the lower left corner of the view is in the lower left of the screen.  It then "sticks" like that until I rotate the device again and then all is good and functions as expected.

So the thing is I'm working through the contents of the TPMultiView subclass but I don't pretend to understand all of it yet (and therein probably lies my REAL problem) but as a stopgap solution is there a way to force the view of the "pusher" VC to appear in it's previous orientation (albeit briefly - and THEN allow it to rotate once it has been displayed) when the "pushee's" VC is popped?

Does that make sense?

**SOLVED IT!  The problem was I had included my own `viewWillAppear` method in LogInVC but I hadn't called `[super viewWillAppear]` so the effect of the superclass was never really going to work, was it! Thanks for the input.  I can recommend the TPMultiView drop in subclass BTW works very nicely.**

Comment: Are you implementing `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your view controllers?

Comment: They're all set to return `!= UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`.  As I say it works fine if I just push everything (eg push LogInVC again rather than going back via the back button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first verify your implementation of `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is correct for all your view controllers.

Then make sure the views of your view controller's have an appropriate `autoresizingMask` set. If you have created the view controllers and their views in Interface Builder you should set the resizing mask there.

Otherwise in your `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad` methods you should have this line:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                             UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: All of the views have autoresize subviews checked.  The scrollview containing the textfields was tied to the bottom left so I have changed that to top left and at least now it doesn't look so awful but it still is NOT applying the effects of the TPMultiView subclass.  I'm going to have to get to the bottom of the ACTUAL problem at some point but I'm pretty sure it will *work* if I can do the following just after the SetUpVC pops:  1. Force the LogIn VC to display itself in its previous orientation then immediately 2. Allow it to rotate to the current device orientation.

Comment: I should add that the point of the subclass is to not have to rely on the Autoresizing and it is something I am trying to avoid as the two layouts are quite different.